# what is the purpose of writing {padding:0 ;margin:0;}

Tags: css

Why do we have to assign {padding:0; margin:0;}  while creating a nav bar. And what else should we set as 0 in css? what happens if they are not assigned 0?

example:
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;}

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we have to assign `padding:0; margin:0;` while creating a nav bar?

You don't have to. But some people prefer resetting the CSS to get the same result on different browsers.

> What happens if they are not assigned 0?

Some browsers may use other values in their internal stylesheet. So you may have some unexpected `margin` or `padding`.

> And what else should we set as 0 in css?

Whatever you want. You may be interested in CSS resets, which do this type of things for you.

Comment: One small doubt- I see several sites have css reset scripts. Do I have to copy and paste the entire script in my style sheet before I start or do I have to pick only the ones I need?

Comment: @Summer The only advantage of not removing the ones you don't need is that you may need them in the future.